# Django CheckboxSelectMultiple widget adds --------- value to query set

Tags: django, forms, widget

I have form with such field:

```
categories = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Field.objects.all(),                       
        widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple, 
        required=False
    )
```

And after rendering I get my first value as shown:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="id_categories_0"><input type="checkbox" name="categories" id="id_categories_0">---------</label>
    </li>
...
```

Yes, I don't have Field Model "------". 
Is it trying to set possible empty value? (same '-------' are used in select boxes to show empty value in the django admin layer).

Sure changing "----------" to "All fields" would be useful (since i will need such option), but how should i achieve that and what causes this weird behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

both your questions are answered in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField

Comment: damn, haven't seen that. Thanx