# Django forms extra empty radio button

Tags: python, html, django

In rendering a model form an extra radio button is produced and I don't know where it's coming from:

```
>>> f = DocumentForm()
>>> print f['document_type']
<ul id="id_document_type">
<li><label for="id_document_type_0"><input checked="checked" id="id_document_type_0" name="document_type" type="radio" value="" /> ---------</label></li>
<li><label for="id_document_type_1"><input id="id_document_type_1" name="document_type" type="radio" value="1" /> Campus LAN</label></li>
<li><label for="id_document_type_2"><input id="id_document_type_2" name="document_type" type="radio" value="2" /> WAN</label></li>
<li><label for="id_document_type_3"><input id="id_document_type_3" name="document_type" type="radio" value="3" /> UC</label></li>
</ul>
```

That first radio button with `value=""` and the text as `---------`, I've scoured my code and can't work out where it originates from?

models.py

```
class DocumentType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Document Type", max_length=240)

class Document(models.Model):
    document_type = models.ForeignKey(DocumentType,
                                      verbose_name="Document Type")

>>> DocumentType.objects.all()
[<DocumentType: Campus LAN>, <DocumentType: WAN>, <DocumentType: UC>]
>>> d = Document.objects.all()
>>> for x in d:
...     print x.document_type
... 
Campus LAN
Campus LAN
```

template:

```
<form role="form" action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p}}
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </form>
```

forms.py:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DocumentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['sections'].queryset = Section.objects.filter(associated_document="Original Section")
        self.fields['document_type'].queryset = DocumentType.objects.all()

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('customer', 'title', 'document_type', 'sections',)
        widgets = {
            'sections': forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            'document_type': forms.widgets.RadioSelect,
            }
```

views.py

```
def new_lld(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            document = form.save(commit=False)
            document.author = request.user
            document.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return redirect('lld:index')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'lld/new_lld.html', {'form': form})
```

admin.py

```
class DocumentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Document Info', {'fields':    ['author', 'customer', 'title',
                                         'slug']}),
        ('Document Type', {'fields':    ['document_type', 'sections']}),
    ]
    inlines = [VersionInline]
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("customer", "title",)}
    list_display = ('title', 'customer', 'author', 'document_type',
                    'date_created', 'date_updated')
    list_filter = ['date_updated', 'author']
```

Comment: Could you post the code for DocumentForm, also what version of Django are you using?

Comment: What does it look like in your template?

Comment: <form role="form" action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p}}
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </form>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label

from here:

[Django CheckboxSelectMultiple widget adds --------- value to query set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243099/django-checkboxselectmultiple-widget-adds-value-to-query-set?answertab=active#tab-top)

therefore:

`self.fields['document_type'].empty_label = None`

does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Django has to have a way to allow None values to be set for nullable fields (fields with `required=False`) and does so by appending an option with an empty value. The same thing happens with Select elements.

Now, for Django to add that option to your Form the `document_type` field must be nullable (indeed have `required=False`), and I can only assume that somewhere in the definition of the Form you're setting that option to the field.

PS: If the form is generated automatically for the Model (i.e. you're using Django's [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)) then the model should have said Field set with `blank=True, null=True`, yet that is clearly missing. ModelForm rocks, though, so if you're not familiar with it, try it out.

### UPDATE:

TBH I can't work out why that's nullable either, but try setting `required=True` manually in the form in the same way that @Alistair specified.

```
self.fields['document_type'].required = True
```

Right under the line where you modified that field to set the queryset. I think that should work.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds plausible, I can't find anywhere I've set `required=False` but I'm going to try editing my models to reflect what you've suggested.

Comment: Well, to be honest I can't work out where it originates from either. As far as I know a `ForeignKey` without `blank=True, null=True` will have `required=False` set.
Hmm... see my updated answer.

Comment: setting this doesn't help, unless I need to update my db, which I shouldn't should I?

Comment: No, by modifying the form you shouldn't... Weird, I expected required=True to work. I'm sorry, I must say I tried a lot of ways, setting required, extra_label, default and more but I can't seem to remove that damn empty option! I'm afraid I can't help you anymore, but I hope my input helps you in SOME way.

Comment: Oh man, yes, you have helped enormously, thankyou.  I'll be sure to post an answer if I do manage to solve this.  Frustating!

Answer (score 0):

A work around is to hide it with css:

```
#id_document_type li:first-child {display:none}
```

Comment: ahhh, nice and easy, I like it!  (though it's gonna bug me until I solve the real problem.  In the meantime CSS FTW) thanks.

Comment: Can you add your view.py and admin.py to your question?  I'm going to dump it in to my demo app and see what I can find.  It looks like it is outputting like a dropdown would.  Are you using django 1.8?

Comment: added, and yes 1.8. Ta.

Answer (score 0):

As Agustin mentioned, [ModelChoiceFields must be set to required in order to remove the blank choice](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0ffa3943fbd100e7de7b1ddbfd301ddc52b57410/django/forms/models.py#L1131).

```
def __init__(self, queryset, empty_label="---------",
             required=True, widget=None, label=None, initial=None,
             help_text='', to_field_name=None, limit_choices_to=None,
             *args, **kwargs):
    if required and (initial is not None):
        self.empty_label = None
    else:
        self.empty_label = empty_label
```

Required is set to False by default, so you'll need to add the following to your **init** in Document Form

```
self.fields['document_type'].required=True
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by adding these parameters to my declaration of my field in my model:

`blank=False, default=None`

So in this case, you model would look like this:

```
    document_type = models.ForeignKey(DocumentType,
                       verbose_name="Document Type", blank=False, default=None)
```